# Custom External Ports not showing on custom IP Core - Zedboard

Tags: hardware, vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I am trying to build a custom IP peripheral (my_perph). I have used the CIP tool to generate the basic perph and now want to add my custom external port (my_port).

Basically I followed this tutorial http://www.programmableplanet.com/author.asp?section_id=2142&doc_id=264841.

I have added the external port definitions to the top source vhdl my_perph.vhdl .
i.e

```
Port(
---Add user defined ports here----
MY_PORT : out std_logic;
```

I then added the port to the MPD file with the syntax:

```
PORT MY_PORT = "", DIR = O, IO_IF = MY_PORT_0, IO_IS = MY_PORT
```

This didn't work so I tried losing the 0 to match the name of the VHDL declared port so:

```
PORT MY_PORT = "", DIR = O, IO_IF = MY_PORT, IO_IS = MY_PORT
```

The issue is that once I have re-scanned the IP library I get the error saying there is

```
NO IO_INTERFACE MATCHING MY_PORT
```

It seems that my custom external port MY_PORT is not being recognised in the IP design although it exists in the HDL of the included IP entity.

And even when I go to add the perph I find that this port does not show up in the info. I am totally lost as I have followed all tutorials and tired every possible thing I can think of!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the Platform Specification Format guide.  You need to understand all of the MPD file, before just copy and pasting lines within it.  The line you have needs to have a matching IO_INTERFACE section (as the error message tells you)

If your IO is not part of a "standard" IO port (see the IO_INTERFACE section of the PSF) you should be able to use simply:

```
PORT MY_PORT = "", DIR = O
```

Comment: Once again I am in debt to you Martin! Just to clarify then when IO_IF is used it doesn't create an IO interface (as I thought), but one has be predefined in the bsb? -  .Many thanks. Sam

Comment: You're welcome!  And you're right about the IO_IF (and it has to be one of the predefined IO types - I don;t think you can make up your own)